# {% extends "base.html" %} and {% block content %} inside if statement (Django app)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In a Django template, I want to show different things to authenticated and unauthenticated users.

Specifically, something like the following:

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="margin">
    {{ group.topic }}
    </div>
{% else %}
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load humanize %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="margin">
        {{ group.topic }}
        <br>
        <b>members:</b>
            {% for member in members %}
            <a href="{% url 'profile' slug=member.username %}">{{ member.username }}</a>,&nbsp;
            {% endfor %}
        <hr size=1>
        <form action="{% url 'private_group_reply' slug=unique %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="unique" class="hidden_id" value="{{ unique }}">
            <br>{{ form.image }}<br>
            <br>{{ form.text }}<br>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="OK" id="id_submit">
        </form>
        {% for reply in replies %}
        {{ reply.writer }}: {{ reply.text }},{{ reply.submitted_on|naturaltime }}<br>
        {% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

In other words, I want to extend base.html only for authenticated users, for non-authenticated ones, I want to have a plain template.

I keep getting a **TemplateSyntaxError: invalid block tag {% endif %}**

How can I accomplish this?

*The app in question is a legcy Django app, using Django 1.5*.

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Comment: No, it's a simplification.

Comment: I think you are missing the closing '%' in the line {% extends "base.html"}

Comment: Oh no, that's a typo from when I wrote it here. Let me correct that. In fact, I'll update the question with an actual code snippet.

Comment: I think your problem is the extends, why don't you define the extended html in your view and send it via context to your template?

Comment: Yep indeed it's the `extends`. Placing it at the top, outside the if-else structure kickstarts everything fine (but obviously, extends it for unauthenticated users too, which I don't want). Can you shed a bit more light on how to get it in from a context from the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{% extends var %}` must always be the first tag in a template.

You can use an empty template and extend that for your purpose.
Try inverting the logic and pulling out the block to the top level:

**empty.html**

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

**your file.html**

```
{% extends user.is_authenticated|yesno:"base.html,empty.html" %}
    {% load humanize %}
    {% block content %}
    {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="margin">
    {{ group.topic }}
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="margin">
        {{ group.topic }}
        <br>
        <b>members:</b>
            {% for member in members %}
            <a href="{% url 'profile' slug=member.username %}">{{ member.username }}</a>,&nbsp;
            {% endfor %}
        <hr size=1>
        <form action="{% url 'private_group_reply' slug=unique %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="unique" class="hidden_id" value="{{ unique }}">
            <br>{{ form.image }}<br>
            <br>{{ form.text }}<br>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="OK" id="id_submit">
        </form>
        {% for reply in replies %}
        {{ reply.writer }}: {{ reply.text }},{{ reply.submitted_on|naturaltime }}<br>
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Best solution here, in my opinion. Just a quick tweak: `{% extends user.is_authenticated|yesno:"base.html,empty.html" %}` worked for me, and not `{% extends user.is_authenticated|yesno:"base.html","empty.html" %}`. You may want to amend that in your answer, for completeness.

Comment: i should also say i consider this a hack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `extends` could be used inside `if` block. Maybe you should consider use other way to do this. And it is reasonable, because you better not do logic thing in a template.

Other solutions will be like, for example, render different template file depends on if the user has logged in.

Comment: I totally hear you on not using logic inside my template.