# Not getting the expected layout(design) on my Django website

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am designing a website using django, following the steps of a course that I've enrolled recently. All the code & resources have been provided to me. I'm following each and every step accordingly but the layout of my website is not similar to what I'm following.
I faced similar problem when I was trying on similar project that I tried before the current one. The layout of my website is way too simple. I'm using the latest versions so i guess there maybe something that I've to include. The image is also not displaying on my website.
It would be really helpful if someone let me know what am I missing.

[This is what I'm expecting:/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu42g.jpg)

[This is what I'm getting:(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy3es.jpg)

This is my main html file:-

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.css' %}">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <!-- Lightbox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/lightbox.min.css' %}">
    <title>Django Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Top bar-->
    {% include 'partials/_topbar.html' %}
    <!--Nav bar-->
    {% include 'partials/_navbar.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <!--Footer-->
    {% include 'partials/_footer.html' %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %} "></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %} "></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/lightbox.min.js' %} "></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %} "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my settings.py:-

```
"""
Django settings for Django_Project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'gwdbwxvan^9g5z-r$g9rf=!zeqrvu*2@^uye!ae#95my3dqp&t'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Django_Project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Django_Project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Django_Project/static')
]
```

Comment: add little bit of code  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you share the html code or check whether you load the static files by{% load static %}

Comment: yes i've used {% load static %} too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect static files, in your terminal:

```sh
django-admin collectstatic
```

Also [here is the official documentation how to handle static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/)

Unless inside the templates(html files), you did something wrong with extend layout. In that case you might find [this link helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679299/extends-base-html-and-block-content-inside-if-statement-django-ap) [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383602/what-is-block-content-and-endblock-content-for-in-django)

Also if you could provide the code of the HTML files that would be really helpful.

At your settings files at the end add these lines

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: @Kalpana I've edited my answer, please tell me if it worked

Answer (score 1):

I think you have done something wrong with static files and media file path.
Please check your static file path and media path.

For example you should define the following things in settings.py file

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Also, make sure that the static files and media folder present in the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your static folder in each template

> {% load static %}

Then you can access your static files and put it for example in image "scr" tag.

> src="{% static 'img/your_image.svg' %}"